# как сделать прогресс бар наполненный картинками react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, веб-программирование, progress-bar

*Такого вопроса и ответа на него не встречал.* 
Как сделать так чтобы полоска заполнялась картинками как прогресс бар (статично,т.е. у нас есть  процент, и в зависимости от него, на столько будет заполнен прогресс бар). 
Картинки ставятся рандомно, их цвет, их положение (голова смотрит влево или вправо). 
[image: Как это должно выглядить]

Comment: меня позицию картиной в зависимости от прогресса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил следующим образом.

Генерирую много блоков с картинками, меняю их позиции в CSS, и потом проверяю каждый элемент. Eсли элемент находиться меньше, чем блок, в котором ширина того процента, то элемент остаётся, если его позиция дальше ширины родителя, то его не будет.